# Play! Framework - Running JPA query for range of values using IN

Tags: jpa, playframework

I have been trying to fetch values from database using IN. I realized that I need to write JPA query like

```
o.country IN (’UK’, ’US’, ’France’)
```

so I tried to write query

```
List result = Playlist.find("id in ?", values).fetch();
```

where `values=set of integers`

but it fails to compile on runtime

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

How do I fix this?

**Fixed**

I also posted this on google groups and got the answer that seems to work

```
List<Integer> countries = (list of integers for ’UK’, ’US’, ’France’) 
List result = Playlist.find("id in (:countries)").bind("countries", 
countries).fetch();
```

Comment: You might want to add this as an answer and accept it - it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not alltogether sure about some aspects of your question:

- I don't know anything about the Playlist class and it's methods.
- What do you mean by "but it fails to compile on runtime"? Does it fail to compile or does it fail to run?

Anyway here's an (modified and thus unchecked) example from my codebase:

In an JPA Entity class:
`@NamedQuery(name = "findFoo", query = "select f from Foo f where f.state in :stateInList")`

There query is used like so:

```
final Query query = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("findFoo");
final Set<FooState> states = new HashSet<FooState>(Arrays.asList(FooState.STARTED, FooState.FAILED));
query.setParameter("stateInList", states);
final List<Foo> retval = query.getResultList();
return retval;
```

HTH